# How do I modify the URL without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, url, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Is there a way I can modify the URL of the current page without reloading the page?

I would like to access the portion **before** the # hash if possible.

I only need to change the portion **after** the domain, so it's not like I'm violating cross-domain policies.

```
 window.location.href = "www.mysite.com/page2.php";  // this reloads
```

Comment: Just to make it easier to understand the question, this is what Facebook does when you open a photo, for example. The url bar changes to point DIRECTLY to that photo, so you can share the URL without losing where you are in the site. Remember sites based on framing last decade? You could only get the homepage url, because only internal frames were changing. And that was terrible.

Comment: While `history.pushState()` is probably the right answer here, in this situation (depending on the exact circumstances...) the possibility of using a server-side redirect (such as via using Apache's RewriteRule directive) is something you might want to consider, or at least be aware of.  Just thought it should be mentioned!

Comment: `window.history.replaceState(null, document.title, "/page2.php")` is probably what most people are looking for.

Answer (score 2434, accepted):

This can now be done in Chrome, Safari, Firefox 4+, and Internet Explorer 10pp4+!

See this question's answer for more information:
*[Updating address bar with new URL without hash or reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)*

Example:

```
 function processAjaxData(response, urlPath){
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response.html;
     document.title = response.pageTitle;
     window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", urlPath);
 }
```

You can then use `window.onpopstate` or `window.addEventListener` to detect the back/forward button navigation:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", (e) => {
    if(e.state){
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = e.state.html;
        document.title = e.state.pageTitle;
    }
});
```

---

For a more in-depth look at manipulating browser history, see [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Comment: Please note the OP makes it clear they are **not trying to navigate to a different origin**; "not like I'm violating cross-domain policies." -- however, I **am** trying to do that, and the [`window.history` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) does not allow cross-origin navigation via `pushState`, (which is reasonable... as the Mozilla site says, " The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise, pushState() will throw an exception.")

Comment: Can I asks what is the value of  response.html? Is that a string of HTML?

Comment: What data should be passed to "response"?

Comment: @EdisonPebojot when you change the URL, you're expected to also change the html content of he page. Where you get that HTML is totally up to the developer and you don't have to do it like in this example. You also need to support back/forward buttons and re-create the page content.

Comment: Is there any workaround for changing it with a different domain? This works only when the target URL is under the same domain.

Comment: @sshanzel there's no reason to do that - are you trying to do some phishing site? - btw, I think it's possible to set the URL to about:blank - but I'm not sure. I saw that - some steam scam.

Comment: @france1 thank you for replying, after some reading, I fully understood the reason behind being unable to make it work. With that, the reason behind was, I was working on a chrome extension with a mirror equivalent hosted in a domain. So when I opened a modal, I wanted to change the URL to have the parameters to point to that specific hosted page. So when the user refreshes, the opened modal with specific parameters will be retained.

Comment: Dang. My app's url has changed due to dynamic hosting that timed out. Now I want to basically transfer the app (that is running in my browser) to the new url without losing any state. Is that not possible?

Answer (score 847):

HTML5 introduced the [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) and [`history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) methods, which allow you to add and modify history entries, respectively.

```
window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '/page2.php');
```

Read more about this from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API)

Comment: Great answer, also can change the current history rather than adding another one, using replaceState(); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API#the_replacestate_method

Comment: I get `A history state object with URL 'file:///C:/Users/.../newUrl' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL  'file:///C:/Users/.../oldUrl.pdf' `. Is it because it's a local disk URL?

Comment: What happens if I use `null` as the first parameter of `pushState()`?

Answer (score 221):

You can also use HTML5 **replaceState** if you want to change the url but don't want to add the entry to the browser history:

```
if (window.history.replaceState) {
   //prevents browser from storing history with each change:
   window.history.replaceState(statedata, title, url);
}
```

This would 'break' the back button functionality. This may be required in some instances such as an image gallery (where you want the back button to return back to the gallery index page instead of moving back through each and every image you viewed) whilst giving each image its own unique url.

Answer (score 194):

Here is my solution (newUrl is your new URL which you want to replace with the current one):

```
history.pushState({}, null, newUrl);
```

Comment: Best to test first with if (history.pushState) {} Just in case old browser.

Comment: This doesn't work any more you will get in Firefox: The operation is insecure.

Comment: And the user can even set a bookmark with that approach, beautiful! I can now update the url on user input and he can directly bookmark whatever his settings are.

Comment: hey kkatusic, thats why Craig Jacobs said TEST. You Test it by trying to execute the new html5 version (test 1) and if that fails you test the older version and if that fails you have problems, if the test succeeds for either object then you know if the brower is new or old.

pretty simple logic buddy! Upvote for Craig! :)

Comment: @GregoryBowers I don't think kkatusic is saying the method doesn't exist, he said it shows a security error/warning when run. So that test would not fail and would still run the function. The test suggested by Craig does not "try to execute the new html5" function, it just checks it exists in the history object.

Comment: This works only if newUrl is RELATIVE or is the same as the current url, and respecting the current protocole, for example if it's https the newUrl should be the same, won't work with http even they have the same base url.

Tested in Firefox (93), Edge (94), Chrome (94).

Answer (score 119):

**NOTE: If you are working with an HTML5 browser then you should ignore this answer. This is now possible as can be seen in the other answers.**

There is no way to modify the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) in the browser without reloading the page. The URL represents what the last loaded page was. If you change it (`document.location`) then it will reload the page.

One obvious reason being, you write a site on `www.mysite.com` that looks like a bank login page. Then you change the browser URL bar to say `www.mybank.com`. The user will be totally unaware that they are really looking at `www.mysite.com`.

Comment: remove it or add html4, because currently it displayed in google search as quick answer

Answer (score 94):

```
parent.location.hash = "hello";
```

Comment: I want to change the URL, not just the hash -- #mydata

Comment: Changing the hash can be useful in ajax as it's a kind of state without using cookies, is bookmarkable, and compatible with browser back buttons. Gmail uses this nowadays to make it more browser friendly.

Comment: @Jarvis: what is the difference?

Comment: @noisy Server side tracking cannot see hashes unless sent to the tracking service explicitly.

Comment: this is not useful if you're using an mvc framework that routes on hash, for example backbone.

Comment: @catbadger I beg to differ. It's _particularly_ useful if you're using an MVC framework that routes on hash. My use case is that my page gets updated via AJAX, but I want the URL to always reflect those updates. If my routing does not use the hash, I _must_ use the HTML5 `pushState()` method, but if it uses hash I can use this.

Comment: This only partially answers the question. We want the url to change, not the hash.

Comment: OP specified in the post that they wanted to do it before the hash. This answer isn't helpful (especially because people who want to and don't know how to update the hash probably wouldn't be browsing answers on a question that says no hash).

Answer (score 84):

In modern **browsers and HTML5**, there is a method called `pushState` on window `history`. That will change the URL and push it to the history without loading the page.

You can use it like this, it will take 3 parameters: 1) state object 2) title and a URL):

```
window.history.pushState({page: "another"}, "another page", "example.html");
```

This will change the URL, but not reload the page. Also, it doesn't check if the page exists, so if you do some JavaScript code that is reacting to the URL, you can work with them like this.

Also, there is `history.replaceState()` which does exactly the same thing, except it will modify the current history instead of creating a new one!

Also you can create a function to check if `history.pushState` exist, then carry on with the rest like this:

```
function goTo(page, title, url) {
  if ("undefined" !== typeof history.pushState) {
    history.pushState({page: page}, title, url);
  } else {
    window.location.assign(url);
  }
}

goTo("another page", "example", 'example.html');
```

Also, you can change the `#` for `<HTML5 browsers`, which won't reload the page. That's the way Angular uses to do [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) according to hashtag...

Changing `#` is quite easy, doing like:

```
window.location.hash = "example";
```

And you can detect it like this:

```
window.onhashchange = function () {
  console.log("#changed", window.location.hash);
}
```

Comment: Would `window.onhashchange` and `window.onpopstate` do the same in this case?

Comment: How to load page contents as well? It just replaces the URL

Comment: Load content as you would normally do with ajax.

Comment: Why do you need to prepend with `window.` ? My code works without it. `if (history.replaceState) history.replaceState({}, document.title, "?newUrl")`

Answer (score 28):

The HTML5 replaceState is the answer, as already mentioned by Vivart and geo1701. However it is not supported in all browsers/versions.
[History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) wraps HTML5 state features and provides additional support for HTML4 browsers.

Answer (score 27):

Before HTML5 we can use:

```
parent.location.hash = "hello";
```

and:

```
window.location.replace("http:www.example.com");
```

This method will reload your page, but HTML5 introduced the `history.pushState(page, caption, replace_url)` that should not reload your page.

Comment: The problem with `history.pushState(..)` is, that if you want to redirect to another domain, the cross domain policy come in effect. While with `window.location.replace(..)`redirecting to another domain is possible.

Answer (score 26):

If what you're trying to do is allow users to bookmark/share pages, and you don't need it to be exactly the right URL, and you're not using hash anchors for anything else, then you can do this in two parts; you use the location. hash discussed above, and then implement a check on the home page, to look for a URL with a hash anchor in it, and redirect you to the subsequent result.

For instance:

1. User is on `www.site.com/section/page/4`
2. User does some action which changes the URL to `www.site.com/#/section/page/6` (with the hash). Say you've loaded the correct content for page 6 into the page, so apart from the hash the user is not too disturbed.
3. User passes this URL on to someone else, or bookmarks it
4. Someone else, or the same user at a later date, goes to `www.site.com/#/section/page/6`
5. Code on `www.site.com/` redirects the user to `www.site.com/section/page/6`, using something like this:

```js
if (window.location.hash.length > 0){ 
   window.location = window.location.hash.substring(1);
}
```

Hope that makes sense! It's a useful approach for some situations.

Answer (score 22):

You can use this beautiful and simple function to do so anywhere on your application.

```
function changeurl(url, title) {
    var new_url = '/' + url;
    window.history.pushState('data', title, new_url);
    
}
```

You can not only edit the URL but you can update the title along with it.

Comment: Works like a charm even for anchors ```window.history.pushState('data', 'Title', '#new_location');```

Comment: why don't you use the 'title' argument as title in pushState?

Answer (score 19):

Below is the function to change the URL without reloading the page. It is only supported for HTML5.

```
  function ChangeUrl(page, url) {
        if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
            var obj = {Page: page, Url: url};
            history.pushState(obj, obj.Page, obj.Url);
        } else {
            window.location.href = "homePage";
            // alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
    }

  ChangeUrl('Page1', 'homePage');
```

Comment: @Green, page is a short title for the state to which you're moving. Firefox currently ignores this parameter, although it may use it in the future. Passing the empty string here should be safe against future changes to the method. From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

Answer (score 13):

Any changes of the loction (either `window.location` or `document.location`) will cause a request on that new URL, if you’re not just changing the URL fragment. If you change the URL, you change the URL.

Use server-side URL rewrite techniques like [Apache’s mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) if you don’t like the URLs you are currently using.

Comment: Can I use "location.pathname"??

Comment: No, changing that attribute will cause a request too.

Answer (score 11):

You can add anchor tags. I use this on my site so that I can track with Google Analytics what people are visiting on the page.

I just add an anchor tag and then the part of the page I want to track:

```
var trackCode = "/#" + urlencode($("myDiv").text());
window.location.href = "http://www.piano-chords.net" + trackCode;
pageTracker._trackPageview(trackCode);
```

Answer (score 9):

As pointed out by Thomas Stjernegaard Jeppesen, you could use [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) to modify URL parameters whilst the user navigates through your Ajax links and apps.

Almost an year has passed since that answer, and History.js grew and became more stable and cross-browser. Now it can be used to manage history states in HTML5-compliant as well as in many HTML4-only browsers. [In this demo](http://browserstate.github.io/history.js/demo/?state=1) You can see an example of how it works (as well as being able to try its functionalities and limits.

Should you need any help in how to use and implement this library, i suggest you to take a look at the source code of the demo page: you will see it's very easy to do.

Finally, for a comprehensive explanation of what can be the issues about using hashes (and hashbangs), check out [this link](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling) by Benjamin Lupton.

Answer (score 8):

Use `history.pushState()` from the HTML 5 History API.

Refer to the [HTML5 History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) for more details.

Answer (score 8):

Your new url.

```
let newUrlIS =  window.location.origin + '/user/profile/management';
```

In a sense, calling pushState() is similar to setting window.location = "#foo", in that both will also create and activate another history entry associated with the current document. But pushState() has a few advantages:

```
history.pushState({}, null, newUrlIS);
```

You can check out the root: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: please add a reference to the supposed "advantages" of pushState :)

Answer (score 5):

These two lines are all you need.

```
    var new_url="Your modified URL";
    window.history.pushState(null,"",new_url);
```

Comment: How is this answer different from Alireza's answer in 2017? All you did was create a variable for the `new_url` - otherwise, it is the exact same answer without the additional explanation. Also, you did not explain the purpose of the "data" or "Title" parameters, or how they can be used. Please delete this unnecessary answer. -1

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited my answer because I copy and pasted from my old project. I didn't explain it correctly and I forgot to change the details. Maybe this answer is not different. But, It worked for me. Thank anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me. I used it into my application in ajax.

```
history.pushState({ foo: 'bar' }, '', '/bank');
```

Once a page load into an ID using ajax, It does change the browser url automatically without reloading the page.

This is ajax function bellow.

```
function showData(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Bank.php", 
      data: {}, 
      success: function(html){          
        $("#viewpage").html(html).show();
        $("#viewpage").css("margin-left","0px");
      }
    });
  }
```

Example: From any page or controller like "Dashboard", When I click on the bank, it loads bank list using the ajax code without reloading the page. At this time, browser URL will not be changed.

```
history.pushState({ foo: 'bar' }, '', '/bank');
```

But when I use this code into the ajax, it change the browser url without reloading the page.
This is the full ajax code here in the bellow.

```
function showData(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Bank.php", 
          data: {}, 
          success: function(html){          
            $("#viewpage").html(html).show();
            $("#viewpage").css("margin-left","0px");
            history.pushState({ foo: 'bar' }, '', '/bank');
          }
        });
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

**This is all you will need to navigate without reload**

```js
// add setting without reload 
location.hash = "setting";

// if url change with hash do somthing
window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
    console.log('url hash changed!');
});

// if url change do somthing (dont detect changes with hash)
//window.addEventListener('locationchange', function(){
//    console.log('url changed!');
//})


// remove #setting without reload 

history.back();
```

Comment: _“I would like to access the portion **before** the `#` hash if possible.”_

Answer (score -20):

Simply use, it will not reload the page, but just the URL :

```
$('#form_name').attr('action', '/shop/index.htm').submit();
```

Comment: This makes no sense

Comment: This requires jQuery even if jQuery has never been mentioned in the question. This calls `submit` on a `<form>` which, by default, reloads the page, which was specifically requested to be avoided. _“it will not reload the page, but just the URL”_ is guaranteed to be false. Why was this posted as an answer to this question?