# Javascript history.back() causes firefox warning

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent Back button from showing POST confirmation alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660329/prevent-back-button-from-showing-post-confirmation-alert)

I have used the `history.back(1)` function of javascript to redirect users to the previous page.  I have linked this function to my back button.  It works, but when I click the back button a JS alert warns:

> "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."

I don't want to show this alert.  How can I remove this alert or use another function that will not trigger this alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you leave a page, store that link in some cookie.  On target, instead of using `history.back(1)`, use `location.href=extractLinkFromCookie();`.

```
function extractLinkFromCookie()
{
//some mechanism to read previous link from cookie
}
```