# How to delete list of items with REST API

Tags: rest, http-delete

I'm wondering about deletion of bunch items using REST API. But I can't find right way. I'm implementing this just by POST method. And it seems as deviation from REST nature. Is there some way with DELETE method for deletion of a collection?

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863326/delete-multiple-records-using-rest

Comment: thanks @MiladAlshomary, now it' clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to do that with REST:

- If you want to delete all the elements, you can use the method `DELETE` on a list resource itself. For example: `DELETE /contacts/` will remove all contacts.
- If you to delete only a subset, you can leverage the `PATCH` method and the `JSON PATCH` format (see http://jsonpatch.com/ and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) to specify which elements to delete. Here is a sample:

  ```
    PATCH /contacts
    [
      { "op": "remove", "path": "/contacts/1" },
      { "op": "remove", "path": "/contacts/2" },
      { "op": "remove", "path": "/contacts/3" }
    ]
  ```

The following could give you some hints: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/implementing-bulk-updates-within-restful-services/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry