# REST API Design - DELETE multiple items using request Body

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, http-delete

I have an API that displays Supplier Products

Our UI will allow the user to select various filter criteria and use that to delete a number of products at once.

The problem is that it takes too long do do a few thousand individual HTTP delete requests:

```
DELETE /api/supplier/6/products/5
DELETE /api/supplier/6/products/7
DELETE /api/supplier/6/products/8
DELETE /api/supplier/6/products/10
...
```

The intention is to make one HTTP call to delete a bunch of supplier products at once.  I can pass a body to the delete so that it contains a list of all the ID's that we would like to delete:

```
DELETE /api/supplier/6/products
Body:
{
  "DeleteIds": "[5,7,8,10]"
}
```

This worked well until we put it behind our production proxy firewall which stripped the body from the DELETE request.

I have had a look at the HTTP Spec  [RFC 2616 Fielding, et al.](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) and it doesn't explicity state that I shouldn't use a body in a DELETE request and further reading has shown that there isn't anything wrong with sending a body with a DELETE request.

I have control over our proxy server and have been able to allow the body to be passed through for all requests, but I worry that this may not be best practise.  We could have thousands of Id's that we pass through and I don't want to us headers or URL parameters as we could run up against length restrictions.

**So my question is:**
What would be the correct way to do a Delete for multiple products **using the body of a request**?  Not just an opinion, but is there actual documented evidence out there for as to why I should not use the body of a HTTP DELETE?

Should I continue with

```
DELETE /api/supplier/6/products (Using a body)
```

or should not use DELETE with a body and instead do a POST to something like

```
POST /api/supplier/6/products/deletemultiple
```

Edit:
There is some good debate in this question: [Restful way for deleting a bunch of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421595/restful-way-for-deleting-a-bunch-of-items)
It doesn't address my question about using the body of a DELETE request for a custom delete action, but there is some good debate on different ways that a batch delete can happen.

Comment: I would go for your first option for sure:

DELETE /api/supplier/6/products

Comment: I agree, use the DELETE rather than POST

Comment: I want to understand if we can POST the ID list. That does work but may not be the correct approach?

Comment: This question should be closed as it is purely opinion-based.

Comment: FWIW, stop looking at RFC 2616. It's obsolete. Use RFC 7231 instead. And no, that doesn't affect the answer.

Comment: RFC 2616 shouldn't be referenced any more. It's been replaced by a number of RFCs in the 72xx range. I think you'd want to consult [7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.5): "A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics"

Comment: So [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) states: A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics;
   sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing
   implementations to reject the request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restful way for deleting a bunch of items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421595/restful-way-for-deleting-a-bunch-of-items)

Comment: You should just delete this question if no answers have helped you thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done both, and when I want to pass several items to a delete action I use a `POST` and just have an `int[]` as the parameter, but I make sure that the URL I am calling is very explicit since I'm using configuration over convention: i.e:

`/api/products/DeleteAllById`

If I am deleting individual items, then I will use `DELETE`.

Comment: That makes sense though

Comment: Yep, we delete individual items by a simple

DELETE /api/products/5

I just am not sure whether to 

DELETE /api/products (with a body) or
POST /api/product/deleteallbyid (with a body)

Comment: My vote would be the `POST` if you are already implementing a `DELETE`. `POST` allows a bigger request, I believe.

Comment: If this is a bad approach, someone please enlighten me.

Comment: It is just not straightforward in common concept. Well, actually, that means concept is need to be upgraded to multi-changing one (CRUD but on sets) =)

Comment: @eocron06 OP has not given us his RouteConfig or anything, so it is difficult to provide an accurate solution. Also, the question is purely opinion-based

Comment: @Mark C - I've been doing some extra reading and found https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/custom_methods 
Looks like google will implement your method of a POST to /api.product:deleteallbyid endpoint.  Nice one!

Comment: @ShaunP Thanks - it's just very easy to implement and to me it just makes sense to do it this way.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should put your ids inside your request URL for this to even work.

Second, batch your request on client side (split it into chunks of fixed id count). Maximum lenght of URL is limited by 2000, so, I suggest to limit your batch id count by 100 or something like this. This way you get maximum performance and minimal network load.

Well, if you want to hack this out instead of using concept of REST and pretty common technique of batching, just use POST and don't bother about batching. Actually, it has some sense in it, because HTML don't even support DELETE =/ It is just faked with some frameworks (Ruby on Rails, Javascript, AJAX, etc)

Comment: I don't that's a good idea. The number of IDs can be vary significantly. Preferable option would be to send the list of IDs in body of the request.

Comment: That's quite the purist approach (which I quite like), however I will have a lot of pushback from the UI development team in having to create a batching mechanism as they use Ember Data

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: What the heck, why everyone downvoted not even providing suggestion?

Comment: Which browsers do not support DELETE?