# What is best practice for deleting multiple records by optional parameters in Core Web API?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm creating a web API for an application and I have a `DELETE` action for a resource. The resource is `Names`, all of which are in a SQL `Names` table. Each name has the foreign key of a `Record` (all in a `Records` table) and each `Record` has a `FileName` and `IsValid` column.

This means that I can delete a bunch of `Names` by `FileName`, `IsValid`, or a combination of these values. This is exactly what the application that will use the API requires.

However, in all the examples of API DELETE endpoints I've seen they are always deleting one record by its `id` and it's making me doubt if my approach is not considered best practice.

This also brings up a question on how would I even do what I want to do? At the moment, my `DELETE` endpoint for `Names` is `api/Names/{fileName}` and I'm not sure how to also include `IsValid` into this. At least one or both `FileName` and `IsValid` values should be required. I do not want the user to be able to call `api/Names` and delete every name in the database.

Delete action in NamesController:

```
[HttpDelete("{fileName}")]
public void DeleteBySourceFileName(string fileName)
{
    _repo.DeleteNamesByFileName(sourceFileName);
}
```

I've thought about adding `IsValid` as a query parameter in the action, but that would still keep `fileName` required.

What would be the best approach to do this, and would such an endpoint be an appropriate for a RESTful API?

Comment: Personally I never delete any records.  You never know if you will need them in the future.  Just create a field for "deleted" and set it to 0 or 1.  (you could use bools, but I prefer tinyints instead of bools)  All other logic follows whether that value is set.  Also seems like you need the UID unless you can guarantee that the filename is unique.

Comment: If you are deleting a file on the server, maybe consider moving the file into a "deleted" folder instead.  Use the UID and table name as part of the filename.

Comment: @pcalkins deleting or not is another issue but here the main issue is how to properly build the URL following the restful style. This is just simple if we consider the endpoint is just a normal web API action, accepting POST request and getting all required data (filename, ...) for the deleting operation.

Comment: Change your action header to this:  [Route("~api/DeleteNames/{fileName})]  [Route("~api/DeleteIsValid/{IsValid}")] [Route("~api/DeleteBoth/{fileName}/{IsValid}")]  
public void DeleteBySourceFileName(string fileName, bool? isValid)  - all 3 routes should one below another

Comment: I think deleting operation should accept just one Id and confirmation should be asked. Filtering by arguments like this looks fairly dangerous indeed :D We do filter but usually the results are shown on the UI first for the user to see clearly what should be deleted. There is one exception when we delete all.

Comment: @pcalkins The `fileName` is guaranteed to be unique. Also, even if I have a "Deleted" field, the problem @Hopeless mentions still remains.

Comment: @Sergey That's not working because the request matches multiple endpoints which makes sense because if I request `api/Names/{isValid}`, the `isValid` could either be a `string` or a `bool` type since it's just text.

Comment: @Lukas using `isValid:bool` in route template may solve a problem in your last comment

Comment: @Lukas I didn't offer "api/Names/{isValid}",  I offered  "~api/DeleteIsValid/{IsValid}"). If you put file name as a parameter you get  isValid=null , since only true or false can be valid

Comment: @Sergey Ahh, I didn't notice. I see now and that makes sense. I know endpoints should preferably contain nouns instead of verbs, but your solution is readable and would work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this code in postman. All 3 routs are working properly. Thanks @PavelAnikhouski for isValid:bool idea.

```
        [Route("~/api/Delete/{fileName}")]
        [Route("~/api/Delete/{isValid:bool}")] 
        [Route("~/api/Delete/{fileName}/{isValid}")] 
        public  void Delete(string fileName, bool? isValid)
        {
            .....
        }
```

If you like, instead of Delete you can use different names for each route for example "DeleteByFileName" or "DeleteIsValid". It still be working fine.

Comment: Indeed this does work! Thank you. In my code I just had the endpoints say `Names` instead of `Delete` since we're deleting the `Names` resource and the action to `Delete` is specified somewhere in the request.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to follow a RESTful approach, I think you can follow one of three ways to delete several items at once:

---

1. `DELETE` with query string, as already mentioned: `DELETE api/names?filenames={file name(s)}&isvalid={true|false}`.

   - It is simple, but has the disadvantage of stating the filters as optional, which you already said are not, since you do not allow the deletion of all the Names. The action code would be something like:

```
[HttpDelete]
public Task Delete([FromQuery] string[] fileNames, [FromQuery] bool? isValid)
{
    // code to delete, but avoid delete with null/empty parameters (avoid delete all)
}
```

---

2. `POST` to a `deletions` resource, return an identifier and then `DELETE` with the identifier, as the workflow below:

---> a) Post request like:

```
POST api/names/deletions
{
   'filenames': [],
   'isValid': false
}
```

to an endpoint coded like:

```
public class DeletionInput
{
    public string[] FileNames { get; set; }
    public bool? IsValid { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("deletions")]
public Task<IActionResult> CreateDeletion([FromBody] DeletionInput input)
{
    // Based on the inputs, gather a list of Names to be deleted
    // and assign an ID to it. The ID is returned in the response
}
```

The response of this endpoint returns a location with the deletion ID (*e.g.* `api/names/deletions/3abf5784`), so that the client can order the effective delete afterwards.

---> b) Delete request to deletion item created: `DELETE api/names/deletions/3abf5784`

- This request deletes the Names list related with the ID `3abf5784`. The action would be like:

```
[HttpDelete("deletions/{id}")]
public Task<IActionResult> DeleteByDeletionId([FromRoute] string id)
{
    // the Names in the deletion list are effectively deleted only now
}
```

(More info on this option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421595/restful-way-for-deleting-a-bunch-of-items))

---

3. `DELETE` with body. HTTP delete requests may have body ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE)).

- Request ex.:

```
DELETE api/names
{
   'filenames': [],
   'isValid': false
}
```

- Action ex.:

```
public class DeletionInput
{
    public string[] FileNames { get; set; }
    public bool? IsValid { get; set; }
}

[HttpDelete]
public Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromBody] DeletionInput input)
{
    // code to delete, but avoid delete with null/empty parameters (avoid delete all)
}
```

- It is also a simple option. ASP.NET supports it, but there may be vendors that do not. However, it is allowed by the HTTP specs.