# Codeigniter when to use redirect() and when to use $this->load->view

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-redirect

I am fairly new to Codeigniter and I am wondering on some Codeigniter best practices. When should i use `redirect()` versus using

```
$this->load->view
```

It seems that when I use `redirect()` then `$this->session->set_flashdata` works like it should but when i use

```
$this->load->view
```

the message is displayed after an additional request.

Comment: Of course `flashdata` doesn't work on the current `$this->load->view();`, as it sets a session value only seen on the next page load by the browser (not the current one).  If you want to pass data to `view()`, just pass it to the `view($page, $data)` call itself as the second parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You probably need to spend a bit more time reading the CI docs.. sounds like your mixing things up a bit....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32866456/412591

Answer (score 7):

I think you really answered your own question.

Use redirect() when a simple flash message at the top of another page is an appropriate response, use $this->load->view() when you're providing an entire page worth of feedback for whatever the incoming request may be.

So for example, when a new user signs up the "Success" page would be a loaded view and perhaps when a user edits something in their account a flash message "Changes saved" or soemthing similar on the same page is sufficient.

Comment: i'm struggling with this though, they just seem redundant although `$this->load->view()` seems lacking in features such as flash message usage. surely you could just get away with always using `redirect()`?

Answer (score 7):

Redirect is also useful for two other common problems:

- When a resource in you app is moved (and you want clients to remember the new URI)
- After POSTing a form as one step in preventing back button rePOSTs

Answer (score 5):

Your observation is correct that whenever you create some `flashdata` it is only available the time. That is because `flashdata` is just a special type of `session` which will available for your on the next request and after the next request it will automatically be deleted. You don't have to take care of its deletion.

This can be tested with the code:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata( 'test', 'testing' );
echo $this->session->flashdata( 'test' );
```

Nothing will be printed. But now the next time execute the following code:

```
echo $this->session->flashdata( 'test' );
```

You will find the required output. Doing it one more time will not give any output. This is how they work. For details check the section **Flashdata** in http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

For the current page you don't require `flashdata` just pass the data to the view. Here is the code:

```
$data['test'] = 'testing';
$this->load->view('sample_view', $data);
```

Bottom line is that use `flashdata` with `redirect()` and for views you should pass variables. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

it's pretty simple. what url do you want the user to be on? if they are on url1 and post data back to url1 and you just load a different view, they will still be on url1. if you redirect to url2, they will go to url2.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to use PRG - Post/Redirect/Get pattern.**
Redirect and load view aren't the same if you have the form in the content of the page.

```
Scenario:
```

There is a view, view_1 with form in it to debit money from a account. After submission of the form in the view_1 you want to jump to view_2 with a success message and you have 2 options to achieve the same. 1. load view_2 with success message or 2. redirect to view_2 with flash data carrying success message.

**Option 1:** load view_2 with success message
When you submit the form and refresh, it will cause resubmission and cause multiple debit from the account, which shouldn't be the case. You too can see the alert popping od "Confirmation of form resubmission".

**Option 2:** This is the right answer 
PRG

PRG - Post/Redirect/Get 
PRG is a web development design pattern that prevents some duplicate form submissions which means, Submit form (view_1) -> Redirect -> Get (view_2)

```
Under the hood
```

**Redirect status code** - HTTP 1.0 with HTTP 302 or HTTP 1.1 with HTTP 303

An HTTP response with redirect status code will additionally provide a URL in the location header field. The user agent (e.g. a web browser) is invited by a response with this code to make a second, otherwise identical, request to the new URL specified in the location field.

The redirect status code is to ensure that in this situation, the web user's browser can safely refresh the server response without causing the initial HTTP POST request to be resubmitted.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

```
Double Submit Problem
```

[image: Double Submit Problem]

```
Post/Redirect/Get Solution
```

[image: Post/Redirect/Get Solution]