# Back to previous page in e-commerce site

Tags: php, url, redirect

I am working with e-commerce site, where user can navigate using filters like category, then subcategory, then Brand and finally product. so the process flow is

```
product.php?catid=1&subcatid=11&brandid=12&prodid=111
```

Now the problem is, when I am clicking on Back button of browser, it asks for confirm form re-submission. But what I want is, it should directly go to Brand filter. I mean to

```
product.php?catid=1&subcatid=11&brandid=12
```

Any kind of help is really appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you are using http `POST` with `<form method="post" action="...">` tags to naviage around, instead of links or get forms, could that be the case?

Comment: since I am using filter according to category, etc., I am using 'POST'. But how to solve this problem?

Comment: if you are using POST,that is naviage‘s restrict ,so there no way i think.

Comment: but ,you can use AJAX to solve that question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the form submission using POST method rather use the GET method. Use one of the following method if POST method is necessary.

[Preventing form resubmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission)

Answer (score 0):

there are to ways to solve this question...

1. using GET instead of POST method...
2. using Ajax..