# Block "Confirm Form Resubmission"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form in my webpage, if one of the fields is filled and the page reloads then appears 

**"Confirm Form Resubmission"**.

[image]

I think that it looks ugly, I dont wanna this call in my webpage.

*So my question is:*

• **What i have to do to avoid or block that call.**

• **Which language i have to use.**

Sorry for my english.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission

review these questions

Answer (score 0):

When someone submits a form, save `$_POST` in a `$_SESSION` variable, then redirect the user to the same page. When you actually process the form itself, then you can delete the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: `if( youTrySomething()) {maybeIHelp();}`

Answer (score 0):

You can either force reload the page in PHP like this

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">'
```

Alternatively, you can send it to another page in PHP, like this

```
header( 'Location: path/to/file.php' );
```

Comment: You haven't given me any code to go off of though. SO isn't a 'gimme teh codez place'

Comment: ok, I have found my mistake. I thank you that helped me