# Confirm Form Resubmission pressing the back button after the closing session (logout)

Tags: codeigniter, session, caching, logout, back

To solve the problem that pressing the browser back button to return, after closing session not will start again without asking for data entry, add the following code.

```
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . 'GMT');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
$this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

But when I press the back button of the browser I get the message Confirm Form Resubmission.
sorry my bad English

Comment: where should I place : $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");

Comment: Within your Controller in which you submit the form. Note that headers  must be sent at first.

Comment: placed in the constructor of my class and when I pressed back button appears Confirm Form Resubmission :/

Comment: The best option is [redirecting (302)](http://hashem.ir/CodeIgniter/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect) the *action* page to itself after submitting the form via POST. Take a look at here for further info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission

Comment: thank you very much friend, I could solve my problem with your help :D

Answer (score 1):

```
    $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . 'GMT');
    $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
```