# How to remove confirm form resubmission with Python Bottle framework

Tags: python, html, forms, bottle

I have:

- `page1`: submits a form
- `page2`: validates it and and returns a page

Now when I click the back button, it does not go to page-1 instead it comes with a "Confirm form resubmission" window.

How do I prevent this? Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3923904), I see this as a recommended approach:

> This is a common technique on forums. Form on Page1 posts the data to
>   Page2, Page2 processes the data and does what needs to be done, and
>   then it does a HTTP redirect on itself. This way the last "action" the
>   browser remembers is a simple GET on page2, so the form is not being
>   resubmitted upon F5.

But I'm confused. Where should I append my redirects? My `page2` view looks like this:

```
@app.route('/StartPage',method='POST')
def test():
    username = request.forms.get('username')
    password = request.forms.get('password')
    return template('StartPage',search_string=search_string,\
                    username=username, \
                    session_id=ses_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

To follow the [POST-Redirect-GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, your `POST` route shouldn't return a template.

- If it can successfully process the form data, it should afterwards
  **redirect** to some sort of success/next page.
- If there's a validation error, it should **redirect back** to the form, perhaps with the error details included in a query string.