# Confirm Resubmission page on clicking back button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my page I have a `droplist` which with `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event, which initiates a POST request to the server on selection change.

Whenever I navigate away from the page to someother page and try to click the back button in the browser it gives me a "Confirm Resubmission Page" since it has a post data associated for the page.

I cant use redirect to clear the post data since i need the data from the droplist control and other controls to be retained even after the `OnSelectedIndexChanged`. Is there any solution to come around this issue??

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission) question. May be it can help.

If you can't redirect to self after your post request then you can do it using ajax.

Comment: Ya but in my application changing it to ajax would cost me much...!! Is there any other way to change the post request to get or anythings without removing the asp.net control?

Comment: Then redirect to same page after post but with query parameters to set your droplist control to specified state.