# Confirm Form Submission with Multi Step Form in Drupal

Tags: php, forms, http, post, drupal-7

I'm currently getting a message from the browser stating it wants to "Confirm Form Submission".

I have a three step form and the issue occurs when you click the Back button on step 3 of the form to go back to step 2.

The form is built using Drupal and it strictly utilize the HTTP post. I have read on different ways in solving this issue which were specified in the following post:

[Preventing form resubmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission)

However, I'm looking if there is a way to fix the issue without having to re-write the entire form.

Comment: After some research, it seems that i had to turn off form rebuild by specifying $form_state['rebuild'] to be false (i actually just have to comment out the rebuild line).  However, i'm not able to determine how to move the user to the second step after the redirect. I need a way to store the step and retrieve it after the redirect.  Thanks.

Comment: i ended up utilizing session to store values across the form.