# Confirm form resubmission on go back

Tags: php, forms, confirm

I have the following problem on my page:

1. On the left side of the page is a search box, on the right side are search results
2. When you click on the search result you are redirected to a second page with details of the chosen result.
3. Problem - when I click back to go to the first page with search results I get a confirm form resubmission.

I understand the problem here but I don't know how to solve it. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission.

Comment: Or simply make the search form use method GET in the first place. Added bonus: Search queries will become bookmarkable/can be shared with other users. (There is a reason the big search engines do it that way.)

Comment: @CBroe so I tweaked with GET instead of POST and I got it working, thanks man!