# Confirm form submission error in codeigniter grocery crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

When i click on back button, i got the confirm form submission error .How to prevent this issue?Please provide solution for this.
I am trying to login to the admi panel   and   edit in admin in this following code

```
 Admin controller:
        public function index()
        {

            $data = $this->data;
            $this->load->view('admin/login.php',$data);
        }
        public function login()
        {
            $data = $this->data;
            $username=$this->input->post("username");
            $password=$this->input->post("password");

            if($username=='admin'&&$password=='admin123')
            {

                $this->load->view('admin/home.php',$data);

            }
            else
            {
                $data['error']="Invalid Username or Password";
                $this->load->view('admin/login.php',$data);
            }
        }

        /* Function For Displaying the home page*/
        public function home()
        {

            $data = $this->data;
            $this->load->view('admin/index.php',$data);
        }
        /* Common Function for calling the View*/
        public function _admin_output($output = null)
        {
            $output->base=$this->config->item('base_url');
            $output->site=$this->config->item('site_url');
            $output->css=$this->config->item('css');
            $output->js=$this->config->item('js');
            $this->load->view('admin/home_page.php',$output,'refresh');

        }

            public function loadSlidingimg()
        {
            $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
            $crud->set_table('tbl_slideimg');
            $crud->columns('imgname','active');
            $crud->set_subject('Frontpage Sliding Images');
            $crud->display_as('imgname','Image name');
            $crud->set_field_upload('imgname','uploads');   
            $crud->display_as('active','Active Flag');
            $crud->callback_after_update(array($this,'rename_slideimg_db'));
            $crud->callback_after_insert(array($this,'rename_slideimg_db'));

            $output = $crud->render();
            $this->_admin_output($output);
        }
        }
```

Please provide solution for this issue

Comment: please provide more explanation. on click of browser back, you want to clear cache??

Comment: @Niranjan N Raju   no  i did not  clear cache.

Comment: im asking, you want to clear cache?

Comment: @Niranjan N Raju  I did not want to clear cache

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the action that took you to that page was a POST request. The browser wants to save you from unintentional double-ordering/paying/whatever when you go "back", when loading that page would need to do the form posted again.

How to work that around? I usually redirect the user to a page which was loaded by a GET request, it can be even the same page, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3968038/357403
Or, you could modify the history: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Also, please see the PRG pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: how to  solve  the issue in  my above code. Please provide solution for this

Comment: What is the workflow? In which function do you enter? Where are you when you click "back", and which url it should be where the "back" goes back? (Please answer all 3)

Comment: $this->load->view('admin/home_page.php',$output,'refresh'); here is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this code format:

```
$this->load->view('admin/home.php', 'refresh', $data);
```

or

```
redirect('home', 'refresh');
```

Comment: the above code is not working . i want to redirect in to the home_page  not to  the home page.