# How does throwing an error on submit allow the form to POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, post

I have a multi-step form which steps through using POST requests to pass state to each controller action.

New > Preview > Checkout > Create

Preview and Checkout are POST requests do not impact the database so form resubmission is perfectly OK.

I am looking to:
  1. Prevent the default submit in order to run some javascript validation
  2. After validation submit the form and allow browser back and forth

While listening to the submit event I have tried to e.preventDefault() and then e.submit(), however, this does not allow for form resubmission when using the browser buttons.

However, **if an error is thrown, the form submits and allows use of the browser back and forth buttons.**

**How can I get this functionality without throwing an error?**

```
$('#new_post').on("submit", function(e) {
    throw new Error();
    // this allows for form submission and back and forth button functionality
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [preventDefault()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) method 
 
**HTML**

```
<form name="form" onsubmit="validate();">
```

**Script**

```
function validate()
{
  if (!validation) { // If the form is not correct
      event.preventDefault();
  } else {
      // Submit the form
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have tried that, however, on this form submission it does not allow for back and forth browser functionality.

Comment: @ebbflowgo Try replacing "event.preventDefault();" to a "return true", and writing a "return false" inside the else statement.

Comment: I don't really get what do you mean with "Using the browser buttons", you are submitting a form, right? The clue is doing so that when the user submits the form, if it is not valid, the form is not actually submitted. However, try replacing the "validate();" inside the form with "return validate();"

Comment: After submitting the form and bringing me to the next page I would like the user to be able to use the browser buttons to go back and forth, resubmitting the post each time

Comment: Weird, usually when i submit a post request i am able to click the browser "back" button and submit the form again. I am really sorry, probably because i am not a native english speaker, i'm not getting what do you mean.

Comment: It looks like it is along the lines of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission

Comment: OK, now i understand. Why don't you use one of the two solutions provided in the question you linked?

Comment: The POST does not persist the data anywhere and the query string is very long so a GET request doesn't make sense.

Comment: It is not that the POST doesn't persists the data, its just tha you don't see them, so, to achieve what you want you can use AJAX or a redirect

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/8fQ0NQkC Of course, you have to adapt it to fit your needs.