# Stop form refreshing and duplicate emails sent from form

Tags: php, html

First of all I am wondering if there is a way to make it so the page don't refresh on form submission but the boxes etc. are still all cleared.

But my main issue is, once I submit a form it sends an email. BUT.... now every time I refresh the page or go back on the website it sends the email again. I can also click the submit several times. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Code**

```
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
            $recipient = "reviews@itssimplytech.co.uk";
            $subject = "Simply Tech Contact Form";
            $headers = "From: $email \r\n".
            "Reply-To: $.email \r\n".
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $headers) or die("Error!");  
        } 
    ?>
    <form class="contact-form" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <textarea rows="5" name="message" placeholder="Say Something..." required></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Submit">
    </form> <!--  /.contact-form  -->
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing form resubmission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission)

Comment: Neither of them really help me since I am a newbie when it comes to PHP.

Comment: You can always search, try searching for "How to redirect in php"

Comment: Now you really are being silly. Where on earth did I mention needing to redirect?

Comment: No need to talk like this,  we are here trying to help, whatever.

Comment: You don't help by marking a question as a duplicate when you clearly don't even understand what is being asked.

Comment: It it indeed duplicated you are looking for how to stop form resubmission, the answer is either with ajax or redirecting, you said you are a newbie in php, i told you to search for how to redirect, that is an answer ! But guess you want us to code for you.