# How to prevent Confirm Form Resubmission message if no need to redirect to form page back?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have 3 pages:

1. index.php: form, method = post, action = "show.php".
2. functions.php: function with form processing (adding to database).
3. show.php: table filled with data which is entered in form and with data fetched from database.

show.php includes functions.php

The problem is the Confirm Form Resubmission message appearing when refreshing page F5 in show.php.

Redirecting back to index.php using header() and exit() leads to infinite loop.

[Method 2:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission) Post + Redirect to self doesn't work for me.

> Form on Page1 posts the data to Page2, Page2 processes the data and
>   does what needs to be done, and then it does a HTTP redirect on
>   itself. This way the last "action" the browser remembers is a simple
>   GET on page2, so the form is not being resubmitted upon F5.

If [PRG](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern can help resolving this issue what steps do I need to do in this case? If no, what can you advice to do?

Comment: which one is table.php ?

Comment: @apokryfos, I'm sorry, made a typo, updated my question

Comment: instead of refreshing page by F5, hit the enter button by highlighting the url in the browser

Comment: You should separate the logic between adding to the database and showing the data. Your form should direct to something that uses functions.php to insert to the database and then redirects to show.php to display the data from the database.

Comment: @sree, well, this doesn't cause resubmission alert. What can be inferred from that?..

Comment: The PRG solution is right - your implementation is wrong, because infinite loop shouldn't happen. You just need condition (or route split) there checking if same script receives POST or GET request (and simply display on GET).

Comment: @sree that doesnt fix anything, we know we can do that

Comment: @shudder, sorry, didn't quite understand. Could you, if you do not mind, give a short example?

Comment: There should be either separate scripts for `show.php` and `post.php` or the redirect (GET after adding data) should happen only when goint go `show.php` with POST request. `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { ....add and redirect ... } else { ...display... }`

Comment: @shudder, I'm a bit confused, because I already use 2 separate scripts: show.php and functions.php (included to the first one)...

Comment: Post.php should redirect to index afetr data is added