# How do i avoid the firefox confirm message "to display this page firefox must send information that will repeat any action"?

Tags: javascript, java, struts2

I am getting above confirmation message in Firefox after submit the form. And if I do same in Chrome there will be no confirmation message. How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When submittjng a form you need to set a REDIRECT to a url not just set a location. This stops the browser from trying to resubmit the from if back is selected.

[Preventing form resubmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission) explains two popular methods. Sorry I can't provide a coding example as I have not used struts, but should be pretty straight forward.