# Form is resubmitted when the back button is pressed

Tags: php, html, server-side-scripting

I have a problem with my contact form that I have made using HTML and PHP. When the user clicks <kbd>submit</kbd> it redirects to another page where the user gets the message, "Your message has been sent". It then automatically redirects to the home page. But when the user clicks the <kbd>back</kbd> button, the message appears again and the form is resubmitted. Consequently I get two identical messages sent to my email!

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you click back you also resend form data. You would be better off to redirect the user to a new instance of the page. By giving a clickable link or just use <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; url=http://whatever">

Comment: [HTTP Status Code 303: See Other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Preventing form resubmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission) and [Prevent Back button from showing POST confirmation alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660329/prevent-back-button-from-showing-post-confirmation-alert) where you will find useful info how to make redirects which won't trigger form re-submission when the Back button is clicked.

Comment: Yep; always redirect after handling POST submission.