# Automatically resend POST request in browser when navigating using back button

Tags: firefox, browser

When I click the back button of a browser, a message pops up asking if I want to  re-send the request or Try Again. I am trying to find out how to avoid this message displaying when a user navigates back to any page using the browser back button. Basically, I want the browser not to ask  for a confirmation before resending the request.

Right now, when testing in Firefox, I get this:

> > Document Expired
> >     This document is no longer available. The requested document is not available in Firefox's cache. As a security precaution, Firefox does not automatically re-request sensitive documents.Click Try Again to re-request the document from the website.

Comment: related https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/922734

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like the system you interact with doesn't follow the Post/Redirect/Get pattern.

1. The client issues a `POST` request to the server,
2. the server does something with the data and,
3. redirects the client to a different URL
4. which the client uses `GET` to fetch.

This way the client can reload the last URL or use the back-button and will not use `POST` again.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) for details.

Answer (score 2):

**Add this in the start of PHP codes**:

```
ini_set('session.cache_limiter','public');
session_cache_limiter(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current Firefox update, to version 29, this has become the default feature when you try to navigate back to pages like search results.  It can be disabled under Options/Advanced/Network and check 'Override automatic cache management'.  Though your question predates this update, it looks like the same issue.

I found this solution on the Mozilla support forum here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1018237