# Show a cached version of the previous form-submitted page in PHP with no framework

Tags: php, caching, browser-cache

I have a page at /form.php which POSTs to /results.php and on the /results.php page, there is an anchor link to goto the /payment.php page.

When someone clicks the back button on /payment.php it goes to /results.php showing

> Confirm Form Resubmission
> This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.
> Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.

How do I show a cached version of the previous page i.e., the /results.php page ?

Using PHP not using any framework.

Comment: The common solution is to do a redirect, especially it is required by the HTTP protocol. There are also answers [suggesting some cache control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226744/prevent-form-resubmission-upon-hitting-back-button) though

Comment: Im not looking at a prevention of the form submission but show a cached version of the submitted form when moved back from a third page.

Comment: I think what @YourCommonSense suggested (use redirect, such as adding at the end `header('Location: payment.php');
exit();` ) will already do what you want -- when you arrive at payment.php and then click "Back", it will move back to form.php (with the data filled by the user, which is already a "cached" version of the submitted form)

Comment: @KenLee no, I am rather suggesting a self-redirect. Then, "When someone clicks the back button on /payment.php it goes to /results.php" without any trouble. Showing a form with the data *which was already processed* is the last thing a developer wants

Comment: AFAIK, "show a cached version of the submitted form when moved back from a third page" is impossible. Browsers would either show an empty form, or ask you to resubmit.

Comment: I'm storing the submitted page (/results.php) into a cached file for showing when reloaded but I can't seem to get the back button to reload the /results.php page as a GET and not as a POSTed link.