# Post redirect get method does not prevent form resubmission on clicking back

Tags: forms, http, post, redirect

I have a login page that presents a login form. On submit, the page will send the data to itself for validation. If validation is successful, the user will be redirected to another page. I suppose this is the POST/REDIRECT/GET method discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/660329).

The following is what I see the network tab on Chrome developer console when I perform a successful login:

```
Name     Method  Status
login    POST    303 See Other
profile  GET     200 OK
```

When I click the back button, instead of going back to the login form page, I don't quite understand why Google Chrome 28.0 still ask for a "Confirm Form Resubmission". Firefox doesn't seem to have this problem. What is the expected behaviour in this case?

Answer (score 0):

1. Redirect to another page immediately after the log in data is
   validated.
2. In the log in page check that the user is not logged in in order to
   show it, otherwise redirect or show appropriate content.

Even though the page can be shown when clicking back (due to caching) the user will not be able to do anything if you check that they are logged in when they resubmit the form again.