# Should I include HTML within my PHP

Tags: php, html, security

So recently I've been using `action="form.php"` in my forms. But now I see that you can do without needing an action, since the PHP and the form are in the same file. Which way would be more secure. A PHP file by itself, followed by another file taking care of the form or both combined?

So would I do? Is it safer?

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
?>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Are you asking WHETHER the PHP and form should be in the same file, or are you asking the best way to have the form point to PHP that's in the same file?

Comment: I'm asking whether it should be in the same file.

Comment: That's purely a stylistic choice, it shouldn't make any security difference.

Comment: @user302975 if you're learning I would suggest that you start learning along with a Template Library it will make your life such much easier when having to deal with HTML and PHP as well as when having to change the HTML without having to change all your code. Smarty PHP is one library you could start with which is very simple to use but if you're using a Framework some of them already have one embed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>`

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<table border="0">
<tr><td> Subject:</td><td> <input type="text" name="subject" /></td></tr>
<tr><td> Message:</td><td> <input type="text" name="message" /></td></tr>
<tr><td> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/></td><td><input type="reset" value="Clear" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $subject  = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
    $email = "example@test.com";
    mail($email, $subject, $message);
    echo "<center>Email sent</center>";
}

?>
```

Comment: `PHP_SELF` is not a good choice. Use `SCRIPT_FILENAME` if available. http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/php-server-vars-not-safe-in-forms-or-links/

Comment: I also believe it would be $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], would it not?

Comment: So what would be safer?

Comment: @user302975 there's actually no difference in regards to safety.

Comment: What about speed? Is there any difference at all?

Comment: @Tuga not true. Using `PHP_SELF` is insecure and allows for crafted urls to inject html/script.

Comment: It's slightly faster to leave out the `action` attribute, since the file will be shorter and it's another variable for PHP to expand. The browser automatically uses the current document as a default, there's no speed difference there.

Comment: @Tuga Nope. As in it is possible to send someone a link that they click on and it injects html/javascript into the source of the page. For example you could send someone an email with a link that redirects a login form to another site to capture their credentials.

Comment: I actually read Jonathan Kuhn's linked article and it suggests leaving action blank or at worst running it through admin_url().

Comment: the article is about worpress and dates `2009/09/21`, too much bla bla

Comment: lol, because the age of a security issue makes it less of a problem, even if it still exists.

Comment: @Tuga regardless, if you look at the examples he posts, it's not hard to imagine it translating to other platforms and general coding, depending upon your background.  I wouldn't be so quick to discount, necessarily.  Besides, isn't action="" less typo-prone?  :p

Comment: @Jonathan here, here.

Comment: @Tuga: if you are responding to a post operation, it's a good idea to set a session variable, redirect using `header()` and then `exit()`. You can then access the session var to see whether to print a confirmation message. This approach prevents [problems with the back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660329/prevent-back-button-from-showing-post-confirmation-alert).