# Prevent the alert of post/module submission on back button click

Tags: jsp, http, post, http-post

i'm writing a web application with Java (with spring/mvc).
To navigate from page to page i use this:

```
function toPage() {
    window.location.href = 'profilo.htm';
    return false;
}
```

triggered by a button. This function call a servlet and the servlet do this:

```
public class HomeServlet extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("profilo");

        return model;
    }


}
```

And after this servlet i'm in profilo.jsp.

Now if i press the back button of my browser i get the alert of the module/post submission.

What i can do to prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Back button from showing POST confirmation alert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660329/prevent-back-button-from-showing-post-confirmation-alert)

Comment: @TJ- i read this before posting.. i need some better help. plz