# Post redirect Get on same page PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

This is an old issue and I have consulted many questions on SO before posting this

[How to prevent form resubmission when page is refreshed via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-via-php#)

[Post/Redirect/Get on same page with firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515349/post-redirect-get-on-same-page-with-firefox)

[Preventing form resubmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923904/preventing-form-resubmission)

and many other.

I have a small app and the structure is like this

```
index.php (acting as controller)

viewsfolder(contains HTML)

models(contain DB insertion etc)
```

When user lands on `index.php` I show him required view suppose

```
require_once(views/signin.php)
```

User submits the form on `index.php`, like from `signin.php` it posts data to `index.php?signin=true`. I call the required function from models and make a **`redirect to itself.`** to avoid form re-submission.

Apparently in chrome and in Firefox I still am able resubmit form and also click on BACK button of browser to go to previous page. which destroys the whole business logic.

I assume that redirection should help here but it is n't
I know I can use AJAX to avoid all of that, but cant i do this without AJAX. I don't think every MVC based CMS is using AJAX on backend.

Is something wrong with me architecture ?

Comment: Maybe you show us your code?

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

Comment: @u_mulder I doubt if it could be of any help, since the index.php is quite messy with lot of IF conditions.