# Is it different things page loading and press enter in adrress bar

Tags: php, html

Perhaps you didn't understand what I meant.Let me explain suppose  you have a code like this

```
   if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    echo "it's ok";
    }
```

If you execute this code  you get the message then after hitting the F5 button the message doesnt disappear.However if you  press enter in address bar then the message disappears

I am really confused about it

Comment: This question almost reads like a comment about *another* question? Please make a question in SO complete in and of itself, so readers have a hope of understanding your issue.

Comment: Hitting enter in the address bar makes a GET request. A form submit makes a POST request. Hitting F5 duplicates the last request. So if you submit a form, you make a POST and see the message. If you then hit F5, you make a POST and see the message. If you then hit enter from the address bar, you make a GET and don't see the message.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-f5-ctrlr?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F5 / Ctrl+R etc. refresh the page. The browser resubmits the *same data* (aka the POST data) using the *same method* as the last request. (This is why [browsers sometimes display a popup saying the request will be re-submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108730/prevent-browser-form-resubmission-alert).)

If you press enter in the url you are performing a "hard" reload which does not re-submit the POST data -- it simply loads the page/HTML via a normal GET request. So pressing enter is equivalent to navigating to the page in a new tab or window.